# What is the measurement of the $\measuredangle PBN$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: In figure M, N and L are points of tangency. calculate the $\measuredangle PBN$. ABD is triangle rectangle.

[image]

My progress;

Draw BE $\implies \measuredangle BEN = 45^\circ=\measuredangle EMB\\ $
E = incenter implies AE, BE e DE are angle bissectors
I drew some auxiliary lines but I still haven't seen the solution

[image]

Comment: "ABD is triangle rectangle"? Do you mean ABD is isosceles?

Comment: @FShrike...The book's statement does not mention that it is an isosceles rectangle triangle only that it is a rrectangle triangle

Comment: Rectangle triangle means nothing in standard English. Do you know an alternative way to describe what you mean?

Comment: Shouldn't the question figure be explained in words like this: "Tangents at M, N intersect at B. The line BM is produced to meet the tangent at L to circle at A. Then a perpendicular to BA at A is drawn.The points of tangency N and L are joined and the line is produced to intersect this perpendicular at I. Then the points I and M are joined intersecting the circle at P."? Could be written more precisely but my point is this information should be written in question so that the reader use the figure for reference not to deduce what I deduced.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha  .It would be better as you say but Peruvian (mainly) and Brazilian books do not follow this rule... Unless there is any doubt an additional explanation is provided. we connected tangency points NL with the perpendicular at A at I. Then we connected the tangency points M to L. The intersection of MI with the circle is P... The triangle is straight at B and Ai is perpendicular to AB. I don't see another interpretation of the drawing...

Comment: @FShrike..rectangle triangle is a right triangle and an Isosceles Right Triangle is a right triangle that consists of two equal length legs. Since the two legs of the right triangle are equal in length, the corresponding angles would also be congruent. Thus, in an isosceles right triangle, two legs and the two acute angles are congruent.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha..for me you don't need to demonstrate the construction...it's clear what the figure wants to demonstrate

Comment: I think that the mother language of peta arantes is either French or a romance language where "triangle rectangle" means "right triangle".

Comment: @JeanMarie..correct ..triangle rectangle = right triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$\triangle LDN$ is isosceles. So $\angle ALI = \angle DLN = 90^\circ - \frac{\angle D}{2}$

$\angle LAI = \angle D, ~$ so $~\angle AIL = 180^\circ - (\angle LAI + \angle ALI)$
$= 90^\circ - \frac{\angle D}{2} = \angle ALI$

That leads $AI = AL = AM$

Now $\triangle IAM$ is isosceles with $\angle AMI = \angle AIM = 45^\circ$

Also $\angle PME = \angle EPM = 45^\circ$

So, $\angle PEM = 90^\circ$.

As $\angle MEN = 90^0$, $P, E, N$ are collinear with $PN = 2 BN$.
($BNEM$ is a square)

So finally you have a right triangle $\triangle PBN$ with perpendicular sides in ratio $1:2$ which is a well known right  triangle.

So, $\angle PBN \approx 63.5^\circ$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that by assumption $AI$ and $BD$ are both perpendicular to $AB$ and are thus parallel to each other. Hence, $\angle \, AIL = \angle \, DNL$. But, by the tangency property, $DN = DL$ so the triangle $DLN$ is isosceles and $\angle\, DNL = \angle \, DLN = \angle\, ALI$ so $$\angle\, AIL = \angle\, ALI$$ which means that triangle $ALI$ is isosceles and if you add to this fact the tangency property, you get $$AI = AL = AM$$ which means that $AMI$ is a right-angled isosceles triangle, so $$\angle\, AMP = \angle\, AMI = 45^{\circ}$$ But $EM \, \perp \, AB$ so $$\angle \, EMP = 45^{\circ}$$ In the incircle, $EM = EP$ so $EMP$ is isosceles with $$\angle \, EPM = \angle\, EMP = 45^{\circ}$$ which means that $$\angle \, MEP = 90^{\circ}$$ however, $EMBN$ is a square so $$\angle \, PEN = \angle \, PEM + \angle \, MEN = 90^{\circ} + 90^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}$$ which means that $P, E, N$ are colinear and in fact the incenter $E$ is the midpoint of the diameter $PN$. Since $BD$ is tangent to the incircle at the point $N$ and $PN$ is a diameter, $$\angle\, BNP = 90^{\circ}$$ Consequently, the triangle $BNP$ is right-angled with $$\frac{PN}{BN} = \frac{2 EN}{EN} = 2$$
However, $$\tan\Big(\angle \, PBN\Big) = \frac{PN}{BN} = 2 $$ which means that $$\angle \, PBN = \arctan\big(2\big) = 63.435$$